# Spring WebfLux - get local interface address of incoming request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

when running spring-boot application using webflux on server which has multiple virtual addresses/interfaces (for imagination `10.0.1.2`, `10.0.1.202`, ...) is it somehow possible to retrieve the local address on which the request was received even when there is load-balancer sitting before it?

so if somebody requests `http://some.balanced.url` which is then balanced to `10.0.1.202` can I retrieve `10.0.1.202` from webflux `ServerWebExchange` or another object?

Thanks

Comment: Look for Forward to header maybe

Comment: [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24174) will be solution

Comment: You can post as answer and accept it